# Retrofit 2 working on the emulator but not on a physical phone

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

image and other parameters successfully upload from the emulator to the server. but images and other parameters do not upload on the server when I try it on my physical phone.

[model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sunTk.png)

[interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ll7kQ.png)

[apiClient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOUcz.png)

[codeInFragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSHfr.png)

Comment: We can not copy from images please edit your question and add the code.

Comment: use this into menitfest       android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"